# Calling JavaScript functions from outside

Tags: javascript, web

I need to input a lot of data repeatedly to a site, which uses a lot of JavaScript. So I cannot simply pass the data to a html form. I am not owner of the site, so I cannot input javascript code directly to the site. Is there any way to call the JavaScript functions with data as parameters from outside? I already considered posting the data with curl or loading the page as iframe, which doesn't work due to security reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drop code in the chrome console.  Also there was a firefox plugin called grease monkey which would be similar.  Otherwise you can't do it outside of a browser.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, seems like Greasemonkey should solve my problem :)